# Looking for the puppy owner's name that had the puppy most serviced by the Puppy Grooming

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have couple of tables: 
The first one: Owner

```
Owner_ID    Owner_Name      
   1           Sam  
   2          Andrea
   3          Gabriela
```

Second one:
Service_Done

```
Puppy_ID   servided_date
1               01/25/2012
2               02/18/2012
3               05/14/2012
```

Third One:

```
Puppy's table

Puppy_ID     Owner_ID
1               1
2               2
3                3
```

I have this code:

```
Select owner_name
from puppy p, owner o 
where p.owner_id = o.owner_ID
```

From here I am stuck. I was thinking of a join between the tables but I am not sure

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Yes, you should use the more modern join syntax. By ordering by the count(*) of the rows in descending order, the first row will be the one that has been serviced the most.

Comment: Take a look at [join syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) and [order by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following will return the top 5 owners whose pets were serviced the most.

```
SELECT 
    a.`Owner_ID`,
    a.`Owner_Name`,
    COUNT(*) as `Times_Serviced`
FROM `Owner` a
JOIN `Puppys` b
ON a.`Owner_ID` = b.`Owner_ID`
JOIN `Service_Done` c
ON c.`Puppy_ID` = b.`Puppy_ID`
GROUP BY a.`Owner_ID`
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

By changing the group by, you could also return the pets serviced the most. You could also group the results by year (or other time period).

Answer (score 0):

The above query will give you the owner with the most puppies serviced by grouping it based on owner and order it based on the occurrences of servicing (descending).

```
SELECT Top 1 o.Owner_Name  --Owner with most servicing
FROM Owner o
JOIN Puppys p ON o.Owner_ID = p.Owner_ID
JOIN Service_Done c ON c.Puppy_ID = p.Puppy_ID
GROUP BY o.Owner_ID  --grouping based on owner
ORDER BY count(*) DESC --order in descending order on the count of occurences
```

Comment: put some explanation buddy!

Comment: The above query will give you the owner with the most puppies serviced by grouping it based on owner and order it based on the occurrences of servicing (descending).


SELECT Top 1 o.Owner_Name  --Owner with most servicing

FROM Owner o

JOIN Puppys p ON o.Owner_ID = p.Owner_ID

JOIN Service_Done c ON c.Puppy_ID = p.Puppy_ID

GROUP BY o.Owner_ID  --grouping based on owner

ORDER BY count(*) DESC --order in descending order on the count of  occurences

Comment: Thank you for providing additional details. For completeness, please put this inside your answer as an edit as opposed to a comment on your answer.